# Switch to correct iframe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, iframe

In Visual Studio, using Selenium, I'm trying to click on a element that's inside a iframe.
The code:
[image]

The problem is i get an error if I use `ECMMyChangeActions` like this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ECMMyChangeActions");
```

Error:
`Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException : No frame element found with name or id ECMMyChangeActions`

Using Selenium IDE I have recorded this testcase and confirmed that a change of iframe is needed before clicking on any element inside this iframe.
[image]

Using `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);` works in Visual Studio but I can still not find any element inside it. So I'm suspecting that iframe index=0 is incorrect.

I have tried figuring out which iframe to use by counting all iframes on the page in this for-loop:

```
[Test]
        public void CountIframes()
        {
            int size = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).Count();

            for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(i);
                int total = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[contains(@title,'Find...')]")).Count();
                Console.Write(total);
                driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            }
        }
```

The output I get using this for-loop is: 000. As I understand this for-loop code, it will only generate a "1" if the element I specified is found inside any of the iframes. So `000` would mean that no such element is found in any of the iframes.

This is a picture of the HTML for that iframe: 
[image]

Please help me find the correct iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe (`ECMMyChangeActions`) I was trying to reach was nestled inside three other iframes. This became evident when reading the html more thoroughly.

```
<HTML>
 <body>
  ...
  <iframe>name="firstiframe"
   ...
   <iframe>name="seconidframe"
    ...
    <iframe>name="thirdiframe"
     ...
     <iframe>name="ECMMyChangeActions"
```

To reach `ECMMyChangeActions` I first had to reset selenium to look at the root of the HTML document:

`driver.SwitchTo().DefaultFrame();`

And then I swtiched to each iframe in the following order to nestle my way to `ECMMyChangeActions`:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("firstiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("secondiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("thirdiframe");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ECMMyChangeActions");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wait frame like this:

```
wait.waitFrame("idFrame");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("idFrame")));

public void waitFrame(string idElement)
{
   WebDriverWait wa = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
   wa.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.Id(idElement)));
}
```

Also, check all the frames that the page has:

```
driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"))[n];
```

Where *n* is the numerator for all the frames.